# Chrome (Beta) freezes when I try loading a certain page

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

Okay, so there's a page that makes Chrome freeze (only load partially). This happens when the page has a lot of images, so I think that might be causing the problem. It does not happen with Chrome Canary, which I run on Windows 10 in a VM.

When this happens, I usually get a bunch of errors like this: `[17095:1:0523/120738.908535:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed`, so I'm guessing it's some kind of rendering problem.

I cannot share the specific page, sorry.

Please advise.

Comment: Are the images important to your needs? As a workaround you could try installing umatrix or ublock origin. The former will allow you to block images entirely from a certain domain while the latter allows you to block any images over a certain filesize.

Comment: You said "this specific page", but forgot to specify the page.

Comment: @JShorthouse: The images are sadly essential. They are generated on the spot if that matters.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I mentioned that I can't share the page.

Comment: What happens if you disable Hardware acceleration?

Comment: @andreihondrari: I think I already tried that, but let me try again, my dude.

Comment: I fixed the question for you. It no longer makes the claim that you are specifying the page.

Comment: It's not like it did before.